# Why I get fragment node instead a node set in this template?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, variable-assignment

Hi everyone!

I'm trying to do a XSL 1.0 to transform XSD but I hava a problem initializing a variable.

**CONTEXT**

Well, here it's the code where I initialize the variable:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="gNS">
  <xsl:call-template name="get_global_NS">
    <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$main_type"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="class_type" select="$class"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

And now, the template `get_global_NS`code:

```xml
<xsl:template name="get_global_NS">
  <xsl:param name="type"/>
  <xsl:param name="class_type"/>
  <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="substring-before($type,':')"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'b'">
      <xsl:value-of select="$ns_base"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'c'">
          <xsl:value-of select="$ns_conceptuels"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'd' and contains($class_type,'A5')">
              <xsl:value-of select="$ns_dom_a5"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$ns_dom_vega"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The variables `$ns_base`, `$ns_conceptuels`, `$ns_dom_a5` and `$ns_dom_vega` are defined as global variables. All of them are initialized with a document node. The following line is the initialzation of `ns_base`:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="ns_base" select="document('../Types/Base.xsd')"/>
```

**PROBLEM**

Well, when I try to use `gNS`variable to select a node when I call other named-template I have the problem. It is a node-fragment instead a node.

Here, the trouble spot:

```xml
<xsl:call-template name="write_type">
<!-- 
  This temaplate process a xs:simpleType or xs:complexType named like the mainType.
  Due to the main_type has a namespace prefix, I get the actual name calling 
  substring-after() function
-->
  <xsl:with-param name="type_elem" select="$gNS//*[@name=substring-after($main_type,':')]"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="fed_type" select="$type"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The problem is just in this select: `select="$gNS//*[@name=substring-after($main_type,':')]"`. `$gNS` is just a node fragment :(

Thanks in advance! And if someone needs more information, ask me for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well any time in XSLT 1.0 you populate a variable other than with the `select` attribute you get a result tree fragment. If you then want to do XPath selection on nodes in the result tree fragment you first need to use an extension function to convert the result tree fragment to a node set. Most XSLT 1.0 processors support `exslt:node-set` (http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) or similar. 
So for your code that means you put `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element and then when you want to do XPath selection on a variable with a result tree fragment you use `exsl:node-set($var)/foo/bar` i.e. `select="exsl:node-set($gNS)//*[@name=substring-after($main_type,':')]"`.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly :) I'm newbie in XSl and I didn't know this extensions...